# Prepend 0 to a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm unsure how to prepend the number 0 to a number in javascript.

Example input would be 1234, and this would wind up as 01234. Everything I try keeps adding the number zero, as opposed to prepending (obviously). Is there some way to escape the character, or some specific syntax for this?

This is for chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String(0) + 123
```

or

```
"" + 0 +123
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function prepend(num){
    return '0'+num;
}

var num = 123;

alert(prepend(num));

//output is an alert box with this text: 0123
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert('0' + String(1234));
```

Using `String()` is a nice way to cast from number to string in javascript. The quotes around the `'0'` make sure that it, too, is a string. Thus, the `+` is going to do string concatenation instead of addition.